# Android Open External Storage Folder in app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm making an android application. I want to access the external storage inside my application. And there will be features such as "creating folder", "renaming folder", "folder deletion". But all these things need to be in my application. Can you give me a sample code? I'm new to this business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](http://thetechnocafe.com/build-a-file-explorer-in-kotlin-part-5-creating-deleting-files-and-folders/) tutorial or can check code of any open source library available like [this](https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager) or [this](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-File-Manager).

Comment: But these codes seemed very confusing to me. It was also written in kotlin. Is there a more open source?

Comment: Just read some stackoverflow pages tagged android and you will find all you need today.

Comment: And dont mark an answer accepted if you need a better answer.

Comment: @blackapps can you help me?